# AWS Lambda from cross account ECR : Lambda does not have permission to access the ECR image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to create a lambda function in account B from an ECR Image from another account A but i'm encountering a **Lambda does not have permission to access the ECR image** error.

I created the following ECR policy following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html#configuration-images-permissions):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CrossAccountPermission",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBBBB:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn:": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:BBBBBBBBBBBB:function:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using aws sso assumed role to perform the lambda creation, i don't know if this has an impact.

Account B and A are not in the same AWS Organization unit.

Things i tested :

- If i remove the condition from the statement targeting the lambda service, the error goes away, but obviously it's not a permanent solution.
- Running an ECS Task using the same ECR image in account B works fine.
- I tried following the SAM tutorial [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/lambda-cross-account-ecr) and i encountered the same issue.

I'm running out of things to check and i would really like to avoid copying the ECR image in account B.

Do you have any idea why the example policy doesn't seem to work ?

How can i narrow the policy from everything coming from the lambda service ? I was planning to use `aws:PrincipalOrgPaths` to allow multiple organization units but this doesn't seem to work with the lambda principal.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me. Are you sure the Lambda function is deploying in `eu-west-1`?

Comment: yes i was using `eu-west-1` although i was also using `"aws:sourceArn:":` instead of `"aws:sourceArn":`... sorry to have made you lose some time...

Comment: Still looking for a way to allow filter using `PrincipalOrgPaths` though

Comment: No problem, glad you spotted it. Those little typos can be difficult to see.

Answer (score 5):

I spent way too much time on this today so hopefully it helps someone else, but I finally was able to share images with entire org using the following repository policy...

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CrossOrgPermission",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "x-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "LambdaECRImageCrossOrgRetrievalPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:ResourceOrgID": "x-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My CrossOrgPermission is a little more broad than what is here, but I believe it should still work as shown.

Comment: This works.  Thanks.  It was a godsend.

Comment: This policy is unsafe and would allow any organization to access your ECR repository simply by configuring a lambda. Please consider [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78240792/2103383).

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, it was a dumb typo, as is often the case with policies.

I used `"aws:sourceArn:":` instead of `"aws:sourceArn":` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws:ResourceOrgID`

This is new feature https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-aws-resources-based-on-aws-account-ou-or-organization/

Answer (score 0):

*aws:ResourceOrgID* will not do what is required in this case. Even worse, it will open your ECR for access to any lambda in any account.

The [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-aws-resources-based-on-aws-account-ou-or-organization/) describes aws:ResourceOrgID as "AWS organization ID of the resource being accessed". This condition is always true, because the resource being accessed - your ECR - belongs to your organization. It does not say anything about the lambda that accesses ECR.

Further, in my communication with AWS support they have confirmed that using  aws:PrincipalOrgId does not work as well. Quoting their response:

> When permissions are being granted to service principles like
> "lambda.amazonaws.com" they do not support PrincipleOrgPaths or
> PrincipalOrgId condition keys. This is because the Lambda service
> principal does not exist within an organization, while an identity
> like a user/role does.

The only way to make it work is to use the aws:SourceARN condition key, explicitely mentioning each lambda, which is going to access your ECR.

Answer (score 0):

When a lambda accesses an ECR Image it does so as a service principal and not as a principal that exists within your org (such as the lambda execution role). Therefore, `aws:PrincipalOrg*` condition keys won't work.

From the perspective of an ECR download, the resource is the repository itself and not the lambda initiating the access. Therefore, `aws:ResourceOrg*` condition keys won't work since they refer to the repository and so are constantly true (thus allowing unintended access to other AWS orgs!).

Thankfully, in [November 2023 AWS released condition keys `aws:SourceOrgID` and `aws:SourceOrgPaths`](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/organization-wide-iam-condition-keys-restrict-aws-service-to-service-requests/). These condition keys can be used to authorize ECR access to Lambdas running in a given organization / organizational unit.

A repository policy statement to grant access from any lambda in your organization might look like this:

```json
{
  "Sid": "LambdaECRImageCrossOrgRetrievalPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": [
    "ecr:BatchGetImage",
    "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:SourceOrgID": "x-xxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```